# Difference between Bash shell and Bash terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal

Ok, I hope this question makes some sense but what is the difference between a bash shell and a bash terminal? Example. When I first open up terminal I have a prompt with my current dir and my user name. In the terminal window header it says -bash- , when I type echo $SHELL I get bash. So by default the shell is bash. Where my confusion comes into play is when I type bash. My prompt then goes to bash-3.2$.Obviously it's a different mode. Are ther any major differences? I have read the man page with no answer. I understand what a bash shell is but just do not get the difference. Thanks for the clarity in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no difference, they are both instances of the `bash` shell.

The reason you are seeing a different prompt is that your initial login shell sources `~/.bash_profile` where presumably you have your prompt set.  When you type `bash` it invokes another shell but because this one isn't a login shell, it *doesn't* source `~/.bash_profile` and so you get the default prompt.

If you were call `bash -l`, (which invokes bash as if it were a login shell) I bet you would see that your original prompt remains

Comment: I see, thanks for clearing that up, i was very confused, i am trying to get a grips with the command line and bash in general, thanks again.

Comment: @Gmenfan83 any time.  Even to this day I need to look at `man bash` to remember the difference between all the various permutations between a: login, non-login, interactive and non-interactive shell